# Maximal values of $k(1-F(k))$ and $\frac{k(1-F(k))}{2-F(k)}$

Tags: probability, optimization

Given a continuous distribution over $(0,1)$ with  cumulative distribution function $F$.

Let $k_1\in(0,1)$ be the value maximizing $g_1(k)=k(1-F(k))$ and $k_2\in(0,1)$ be the value maximizing $g_2(k)=\frac{k(1-F(k))}{2-F(k)}$. Is it true that $k_1\leq k_2$ always?

For example, for the uniform distribution with $F(k)=k$, the value $k_1$ maximizing $k(1-k)$ is $1/2$, while the value $k_2$ maximizing $\frac{k(1-k)}{2-k}$ is approximately $0.59>1/2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true, and it can be shown using a similar argument as in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1851846/maximizing-fracx1-fx3-fx/1851847#1851847).

We know that
$$k_1(1-F(k_1))\geq k_2(1-F(k_2))$$
and
$$\frac{k_1(1-F(k_1))}{2-F(k_1)}\leq\frac{k_2(1-F(k_2))}{2-F(k_2)}$$
which implies
$$2-F(k_1)\geq 2-F(k_2)$$
or
$$F(k_1)\leq F(k_2)$$
hence
$$k_1\leq k_2.$$