# Maximizing $\frac{x(1-f(x))}{3-f(x)}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, optimization

Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$ be a nondecreasing function such that $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$.

Let $x_1\in[0,1]$ be the value maximizing $x(1-f(x))$.

Let $x_2\in[0,1]$ be the value maximizing $\frac{x(1-f(x))}{3-f(x)}$.

Is it always true that $x_1\leq x_2$?

**Example**: $f(x)=x$. Then $x_1=0.5$ and $x_2=3-\sqrt{6}\approx 0.55$, so $x_2>x_1$.

It seems to be true because the denominator $3-f(x)$ is a decreasing function in $x$, so it gives an advantage to larger $x$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We know that
$$
x_1(1 - f(x_1)) \geq x_2(1 - f(x_2))
$$
and
$$
\frac{x_1(1-f(x_1))}{3-f(x_1)} \leq \frac{x_2(1-f(x_2))}{3-f(x_2)}
$$
Consequently, it must be true that
$$
3 - f(x_1) \geq 3 - f(x_2)
$$
i.e.
$$
f(x_2) \geq f(x_1)
$$
Because $f$ is non-decreasing, we have
$$
x_2 \geq x_1
$$

Comment: Neat argument! I couldn't see that myself.